Sampling a binary time series and estimating proportion of 1s - why is the error less when the time series has longer contiguous regions
I've been messing around with a dataset that can be abstracted to a binary time series. That is to say a series of values that can be either 1 or 0, each representing a millisecond of time.
I am attempting to estimate the proportion of 1s from a sample of this time series. The simplest cases is sampling every thousandth element, but I've also messed around a bit with random sampling.
Estimating the proportion of 1s is no problem. The best estimator is simply the proportion of the sample that is 1. I was pretty convinced that the standard error of this estimate would also be very straightforward, being equal to the standard error of a proportion sqrt(p(1-p)/n) potentially with a finite population correction for very high sampling rates.
However, I've observed something that seems kind of intuitive but I can't figure out any good way to quantify. When the time series is effectively a random sequence, such that there is no correlation between subsequent elements the error I observed over multiple runs perfectly matches the formula. When I construct the sequence from contiguous regions of 1s and 0s, the error gets smaller. This feels intuitive because I'be introduced a correlation between the values being sampled and the values nearby which makes my sampling more effective, but I can't figure out how I would estimate this error a priori with some information about the series (for example the average length of contiguous regions or some such). Can anyone help me out? Or even just give me a more robust qualitative way to think about this effect?
Update: more on my methodology
I'm working with simulated data, so I have the luxury of being able to quantify the true error. Each series generated by my simulation is one hour (i.e. 3600000ms long) and the regions of interest (i.e the contiguous regions where the value is set to 1) are generated as follows:

The start times are randomly distributed taking the time from one start to the next from an exponential distribution with mean 500ms. This is equivalent to there being a 1/500 chance of a new region starting each step.
The length of the region is randomly generated from a uniform distribution with min 1ms and max 199ms
Some post-processing is applied to 'queue' regions that would overlap based on the generated start and duration but this is fairly rare for these parameters.

The chart below shows the result of sampling such series at a range of frequencies. Each box and whisker represents the relative error over 500 runs at the given frequency. The whiskers are set to the 90th percentile relative error. The red line is the calculated using the standard error of a proportion (multiplied by 1.68 to give a 90% CI). You can see that at lower sampling frequencies the red line is a good approximation of the error, but it gets systematically worse.

It feels like I need another correction factor, analagous to the finite population correction, to represent the decreasing number of contiguous regions.
Of course even if I can figure this out, it is likely that such a correction factor would require one to have a lot of 'a priori' information about the true content of the series, which isn't necessarily true in real-world applications.
Random sampling destroys the effect
Fascinatingly, if I change my sampling to also be random (again, with a 1/1000 chance of sampling a given ms) it totally destroys the effect. I'm wondering if the third bullet point of my methodology is somehow to blame here... more simulations needed!


When you say that the error goes smaller, something does not compute. If you calculate the proportion $p$ from the sample data (the mean), and the standard deviation $s$ also from the sample data, then the standard error ($\frac {s} {\sqrt n}$) will be very close to the formula ($\frac {\sqrt {p.(1-p)}} {\sqrt n}$ (note that it will not be "exactly" the same, unless your sample size is quite large -many thousands-). Mathematically, it has to match: a binary distribution can not escape the relationship between its mean ($p$) and variance ($p(1-p)$).
But, if you compare the obtained standard error, to either the "theoretical" standard error (the one using the value of $p$ which you used to "construct" your dataset, from which you sampled, or compare it to the value of $p$ you obtain when the sequence is "random", then, yes, you could see a difference.
I am pretty sure that, if you look at the proportion in the sample drawn from "contiguous" regions, it will be different from the theoritical one, and/or from the one observed from "random" datasets.
Why could this be? Because of sampling aliasing. By creating contiguous regions, you introduced a distinct low frequency pattern in your data which your sample rate (every thousandth) does not capture. Hence you have an aliased sample, which produces an aliased $p$, so you actually observe a different proportion (from what you expected; not from what that sample says). If $p$ is different, so will the standard error. W/o this pattern of contiguous sections, your dataset is basically white noise; your sample rate is fine, it will catch every frequency with basically equal probability.
Therefore, I am also pretty sure that this behavior does not occur when you use random sampling.
So it is not that the standard error changes, it is that the observed proportion changes (because you now have a biased estimator), and therefore everything else (variance, standard error) changes with it.

Thanks for your reply. There's certainly potential for me to introduce aliasing if there's a strong correlation between the sampling and the frequency of the contiguous regions. And in this case you're correct that my estimator becomes biased. However I haven't observed any bias in the estimator in the tests I've been running. I should have mentioned that I'm working with simulated data at the moment so I can do thousands of runs and calculate the true error. I'll share some more data from my simulations in the original post when I get time to update.

You're correct that I'm not using the measured p though. I'm actually using the expected p based on the parameters used to create the series. I'll look into whether anything weird might be happening there. In the meantime I added a load more detail.

Your details confirm my diagnostic (e.g. "Random sampling destroys the effect"). YOU are absolutely aliasing, not because a correlation between sampling rate and frequency of contiguous regions; because you are sampling at a lower frequency as the Nyquist rate (NYquist-Shannon sampling theorem: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). This is not so much a statistical question, but a signal processing/information theory question. The explanation lies not in statistics, but in sampling theory.

Interesting. I always thought the Nyquist theorem was about the sampling frequency required to recreate the original series from sampling without spurious low frequencies appearing. In this case I'm not primarily interested in recreating the series, in fact I'm hardly interested in the series at all. I'm just (incorrectly it seems) treating it as a population of which I wish to measure a proportion.
If this is aliasing, why is it making my sampling better (i.e. lower error, and still no bias) and why is the effect stronger at high sampling frequencies rather than low?

My "hunch" is that the $p$ you use to simulate the data is near 0.5. This is the max variance for the binomial distribution. Because of aliasing, you are measuring either a higher or a lower proportion, and in both cases the variance will be lower, hence lower standard error. And I seriously doubt that the effect is stronger if you sample at higher frequencies (that would mean you proved Nyquist wrong...). E.g. if you were to sample every 50 datapoints, the effect would go away (with a large enough sample size, to capture a "representative" sample).

If aliasing results in you not properly recreating the time series, why do you bekieve that the measured proportion is not affected? If there is aliasing, the measured proportion is not the true proportion, because the measured signal is not the true signal.

I believe the measured proportion is not affected because, as shown in the chart, the true error (i.e. difference between the true proportion and the one estimated from sampling) has a mean of zero and a much smaller 90th percentile range than predicted based on sampling a proportion. That is to say, I'm getting very precise unbiased measurements from the sampled data.
